# Android: Handling cookies with Webviews now that Apaches HTTP methods are deprecated?

Tags: android, cookies, webview, request, http-post

I'm trying to make a post request that gives me a JSON. in the request, the header contains a header with a cookie.
Later, I need to attach(?) that cookie to a WebView (along with the proper URL).

Now that all the apache requests and CookieSyncManager are deprecated, I'm kinda lost.

This is my code, and it doesn't work.

post request code:

```
    public static String callJsonPost(String urlString) {

    String data = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(true);

        // Set cookies in requests
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(conn.getURL().toString());
        if (cookie != null) {
            conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
        }

        conn.connect();

        // Get cookies from responses and save into the cookie manager
        List<String> cookieList = conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
        if (cookieList != null) {
            for (String cookieTemp : cookieList) {
                cookieManager.setCookie(conn.getURL().toString(), cookieTemp);
            }
        }

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

        data = convertStreamToString(in);
        in.close();

    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return data;
}
```

webview with cookie attachment code:

```
public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_webview_fragment, container, false);

        mWvMain = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.mWvMain);

        CookieManager cookies = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookies.setAcceptCookie(true);
        cookies.setCookie(mUrl, "Cookie");

        mWvMain.loadUrl(mUrl);

        mWvMain.setWebViewClient(WebViewManager.sharedInstance());
        WebSettings s = mWvMain.getSettings();
        s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        s.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        s.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        s.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        s.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        s.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        s.setAllowContentAccess(true);

        return view;
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

**Update**
After testing, I do get the cookie from the call. The remaining question is how do I implement the cookie to the webviews header?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What are your *specific* symptoms?

Comment: The cookie is not attached to the webview.
I don't know if the problem is with the request (getting the cookie) or in with the webview (implementing the cookie)

Comment: "I don't know if the problem is with the request (getting the cookie) or in with the webview (implementing the cookie)" -- well, you should be able to narrow that down via a debugger or logging statements. Off the cuff, `get("COOKIE-NAME")` doesn't look right. Last I checked, cookies are set with `Set-cookie` headers. A search on `httpurlconnection cookies` on a major search engine turns up lots of material on how to get cookie headers using `HttpUrlConnection`, such as http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html.

Comment: Hey, I have updated the code. the tutorial you gave me was very helpful.
The remaining question is how do I implement the cookie to the webviews header?

Comment: If nothing else, there's a version of `loadUrl()` that takes in additional headers for the HTTP request. However, that's likely to break in the face of a server-side redirect. There may be other options for adding cookies to the `WebView`, but I haven't ever tried that and don't recall exactly where in the classes there might be an option for it.